# How to resolve issue with Office Interop Assemblies on VB6 exe installation?

Tags: excel, vb6, installation, excel-interop

I have developed one trading application using VB6. In that, I have used Excel application object as below (Excel.Application).

```
Set xl = New Excel.Application
Set xlwbook = xl.Workbooks.Add
Dim xlsheet As Worksheet
Set xlsheet = xlwbook.Sheets.Item(1)
```

And, I have created the installer for that VB6's exe using Advanced Installer with prerequisites as **Office 2010 Primary Interop Assemblies** points to - **o2010pia.msi** (To enable the option to access Excel.Application).

I am unable to run installed application even installed the Office 2010 Primary Interop Assemblies. It throws **Object Required** error.

**Note:** I have googled regarding this, many of them suggested their solution for C# and/or VB .Net environment. I want it for VB6 environment.

Please help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need interop assemblies?  Aren't they to provide a .NET interface to the Office products.  VB6 will be talking normal COM so shouldn't need anything.  Which line of code is getting the error?

Comment: Set xl = New Excel.Application - i am getting the error.

Comment: So, how the program calls excel application object without the interop assemblies. Since, client machine doesn't have MS Office installed.

Comment: OK, if you don't have Office on the PC then it won't ever work.  The Interop Assemblies just give you a gateway to call Office.  If your program needs to create Office documents without having Office installed then you need to look at another solution.  .NET applications can use OpenXML but you may have to look at, perhaps, just creating CSV files?

Comment: so, Office interop assemblies create a bridge with Office and development tool. If I need to use excel in VB6.. end machine should have MS Office installed?

Comment: That's about it.  VB6 can talk to Office through COM directly and so doesn't need the interop assemblies.  C# and VB.NET use the interop assemblies to talk to Office through COM.  But you're right you will need Office on the end user machine.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll summarize the comment thread as an answer.  The OP has written a VB6 application that uses COM to create Excel spreadsheets.  He was including the Office interop assemblies as part of his install but his code to create spreadsheets wasn't working.  The reason for this is that Office was not installed on the end user computer.

The Office Interop Assemblies only give .NET applications an interface through which they can talk to the COM interface of an installed MS Office application, they don't provide Office functionality.  In the OP's case he wouldn't need them as VB6 can talk directly to the COM interface of MS Office.

The OP either needs to install Office on his end user computers or generate his spreadsheets in a different way, maybe as a CSV.